# git not detecting changes to files

Tags: git

I recently set up a repository on Git and wanted two versions of the code (with some slight variations between them) so I copied the folder containing the repo and renamed it. The two folders were in the same directory.

I ended up deleting the original copy and renaming the second folder to the original name. Git is no longer detecting the changes to any files and I think this is the reason why. I do not know how to fix this issue.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

thanks
RW

Comment: What do you see if you run `git status` in the new directory?

Comment: I get              On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean

Answer (score 2):

There should be only 1 !!!! `.git` folder in your project unless you have some submodules. If you have submodule each folder should contains its own `.git` folder.

It looks like you have moved/deleted the `.git` folder so your root is no longer a git repository.

If you dont have the "old" `.git` folder you can do the following:

```
cd <root>
git init
git remote add <url>
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There's only one .git folder. The other hidden files are .gitignore files.  I did copy the folder that contained the original .git folder (to the same directory) then I deleted the original folder. I think that is the problem but I'm not sure how to fix it. It is still showing up as a repository, just not detecting any changes.

Answer (score 1):

You may have accidentally erased .git directory. In case that's what happened check this link ( http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html ).

Comment: There is a .git folder inside the folder (and each folder inside that) but not one in the same directory as the top level folder. Should there be?

Comment: this may help https://community.webfaction.com/questions/4112/recommended-git-repository-structure

Comment: sorry- my mistake, the files within the sub folders are .gitignore files not .git folders. apologies for that.